# Azure DevOps - React App - Set Environment Variables in Release Pipeline

Tags: reactjs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We have a React app in AzureDevOps.  We build it using `npm install/npm run` build and then upload the zip file.  From there we'll do a release to multiple stages/environments.  Due to SOX compliance we're trying to maintain a single build/artifact no matter what the environment.

What I'm trying to do is be able to set the environment variables during the **release pipeline**.  For instance, be able to substitute the value of something like `process.env.REACT_APP_CONFIG_VALUE`

I've tried setting that in the Pipeline variables during the release but it does not seem to work.  Is this possible or do I have to use a json config of some sort instead of using process.env?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could not achieve this by setting pipeline variables during the release.

Suggest you could use [RegEx Match & Replace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kasunkodagoda.regex-match-replace&targetId=ca4e4e67-3099-4c62-9ea9-bef80e0cc70a&utm_source=vstsproduct&utm_medium=ExtHubManageList) extension task to achieve this. Use this site to convert the regular expression: [Regex Generator](https://regex-generator.olafneumann.org/?sampleText=this._baseUrl%20%3D%20process.env.REACT_APP_CONFIG_VALUE%3B&flags=i&onlyPatterns=false&matchWholeLine=false&selection=16%7CCharacter,34%7CMultiple%20characters,38%7CMultiple%20characters,45%7CMultiple%20characters)

Here is an example:

```
this._baseUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_CONFIG_VALUE;
```

This extension task will use regular expressions to match fields in the file.

[image]

[image]

Checking from published js.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it -

**Step1:** Add all those files (.env .env.development .env.production) to azure devops library as secure files. We can download these secure files in the build machine using a DownloadSecureFile@1 pipeline task (yml). This way we are making sure the correct .env file is provided in the build machine before the task yarn build --mode development in the pipeline.

[image]

**Step2:** Add the following task in your azure yml pipeline in appropriate place. I have created a github repo **https://github.com/mail4hafij/react-yarn-azure-pipeline** if you want to see a complete example.

```
  # Download secure file from azure library
  - task: DownloadSecureFile@1
    inputs:
      secureFile: '.env.development'

  # Copy the .env file
  - task: CopyFiles@2
    inputs:
      sourceFolder: '$(Agent.TempDirectory)'
      contents: '**/*.env.development'
      targetFolder: '$(YOUR_DEFINED_PROJECT_ROOT_FOLDER_VARIABLE)'
      cleanTargetFolder: false
```

Keep note, secure files can't be edited but you can always re-upload.